# Why is `return` not allowed in Kotlin init block?

Tags: kotlin

If I compile this:

```
class CsvFile(pathToFile : String)
{
    init 
    {
        if (!File(pathToFile).exists())
            return
        // Do something useful here
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Error:(18, 13) Kotlin: 'return' is not allowed here

I don't want to argue with the compiler, but I am curious about the motivation behind this restriction.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is not allowed because of possible counter-intuitive behavior with regard to several `init { ... }` blocks, which might lead to subtle bugs:

```
class C {
    init { 
        if (someCondition) return
    }
    init {
        // should this block run if the previous one returned?
    }
}
```

<sup>If the answer is 'no', the code becomes brittle: adding a `return` in one `init` block would affect the other blocks.</sup>

A possible workaround that allows you to finish a single `init` block is to use some function with lambda and [a labeled return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

```
class C {
    init {
        run {
            if (someCondition) return@run
            /* do something otherwise */
        }
    }
}
```

Or use an explicitly defined [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors):

```
class C {
    constructor() { 
        if (someCondition) return 
        /* do something otherwise */
    }
}
```

Comment: Using multiple init blocks, you can keep initialization logic close to the member declarations. Sometimes you may also want to split a single init blocks to place a property with an initializer inbetween, as property initializers and init blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the code.

Comment: That would be a very weird use case, and it's not intuitive for me to see multiple `init` calls (multiple times to initialize the object...). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Requested here to still allow "return" inside "init", and in case of multiple "init", only then to warn about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30585/Request-provide-a-way-to-use-return-inside-init-block